# MVC Interface and Repository Difference

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, interface, repository

I notice code where people create both 1) Interface and 2) Repository. Interface lists all data Crud operations, and Repository actually defines data Crud operations. Why not just combine them into one class? I heard it is something with level of abstraction? Why are they in two separates places? I am beginner so trying to learn the separation. Thanks,

Resources: [Implementing Repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application), [Implement Repository Pattern](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/dhananjay_kumar/posts/how-to-implement-the-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public interface IStudentRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents();
        Student GetStudentByID(int studentId);
        void InsertStudent(Student student);
        void DeleteStudent(int studentID);
        void UpdateStudent(Student student);
        void Save();
    }
}


namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private SchoolContext context;

        public StudentRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return context.Students.ToList();
        }

        public Student GetStudentByID(int id)
        {
            return context.Students.Find(id);
        }

        public void InsertStudent(Student student)
        {
            context.Students.Add(student);
        }

        public void DeleteStudent(int studentID)
        {
            Student student = context.Students.Find(studentID);
            context.Students.Remove(student);
        }

        public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
        {
            context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining an interface, the consumer of your repository, which may be a Controller class, only needs to depend on your interface `IStudentRepository` and be [loosely coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling). This follows the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://deviq.com/dependency-inversion-principle/). You can read more about these concepts from the topic of [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

A specific use case for it is that if one day you decide to change the implementation details of the CRUD operations in your repository, you can register this new service and do not require any changes on the consumer side of your repository (assuming you are making use of a dependency injection service).

Comment: dont you mean, "which may be a Controller class, only needs to depend on the Repository"?  in the MSDN example, the controller depends on the repository

Comment: What I meant is that the Controller depends on your `IStudentRepository`, instead of `StudentRepository`.

Comment: The MSDN article you linked does not use a dependency injection service and will not fully demonstrate the benefits of this pattern. However, in your second article that you linked, the last section does go through dependency injection.